# How to fix string in objective-c?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm having a problem with the correct answer

When the user types in lets say "dog" the answer is right!

But if s/he types in "dog " <--- with a spacebar its wrong,

how do i fix this:

Code:

```
- (IBAction)btncheck:(id)sender {


    if ([_textbox.text isEqualToString:@"q"]) {

        _keyboard.hidden = YES;
        _textXclear.hidden = YES;
    }
    else {
        // Was not correct.  Notify user, or just don't do anything  
    }
```

and id like to notify user that the answer was not correct by placing an image, how is that done

Comment: A simple Google search for "NSString remove whitespace at end of string" would [have revealed lots of suggestions](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=NSString+remove+whitespace+at+end+of+string&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Comment: no, I need multiple right answers! such as "dog... " "dog.....  " & "dog.......    "

with spaces in between

Comment: Yes, trim the string first to get rid of all whitespace, then "dog", "dog " and " dog " will all become "dog", and you can then check if your user entered "dog".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the method stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet to get rid of leading or trailing spaces:

```
NSString *string = [_textbox.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: whitespaceCharacterSet];
if (string isEqualToString: "q")
{
   //string is wrong? If so, display an error message.
}
else
{
  //string is correct, resign first responder
}
```

You should do a search on NSString in the Xcode help system and read the NSString class reference. There are tons of useful methods in the NSString class for doing things like this.

I'm confused, because in your previous post I thought that the answer "q" was the correct answer. In your code above, anything but q would be correct.

As far as placing an image, the easiest thing to do is probably to put an image view, with image installed, in your view controller, but set it's hidden property to YES. Then, when you decide the user has entered the correct answer, set the image view's hidden property to NO to reveal it.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was more in depth, 

The image info is very useful, but how do I do that if the answer is Incorrect? I want it to appear when the user presses check and its incorrect, the image should appear then!!!?

Comment: Yep and moreover better then mine.

Comment: Ok, so you can have a "correct" image and an "incorrect" image, linked to separate outlets, and make them both hidden. Then when the user enters an answer, show the appropriate image and hide the other one.